# BB-UN300 vs BB-UN54 bottom bracket durability

Tags: bottom-bracket

These 2 bottom brackets are the most widely available ones in my country. Which is the best in terms of reliablity, quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are standard square taper bottom brackets, so **either will work** for you.  The one you can get today is probably better than the out-of-stock one.

That said, the UN54 is a development of the UN52 from the 90s, and has spawned the UN55 as a follow-on.

The UN55 costs more than the UN300 (according to some quick searching, YMMV) and that suggests the UN5x is likely to contain better quality materials.

The UN300 is in the Tourney groupset, whereas the UN55 is not in a groupset officially.  Given that Tourney is the bottom most groupset, I'd go for the UN55, as long as pricing isn't crazy.

---

Upshot - both would work fine, but I'd choose the 54 or 55 over the 300.